# Unable to detect Webcam while using JMF on macOS

Tags: java, macos, jmf

I've installed JMF-2.1.1e via zip files on my macOS.
But it seems that the jmstudio is unable to detect my Webcam on my MacBook Pro.
Through the JMF is really an old framework to use, but it is ordered to be used in my coursework.
By the way, the Windows version of JMF installer can not run properly on my Windows10 64bit PC.

Comment: *"Through the JMF is really an old framework to use, but it is ordered to be used in my coursework."* I've successfully used JMF for turning still images into video files, and playing MP3s. That being said, it should not be part of any 'coursework' today, given development on it was abandoned over a decade ago! Either get the instructors to realise the course needs to be updated, or find a new course.

Comment: Well,I'm ready to install VMWare to solve the problem.